# How to approach reporting errors in an interpreter?

Tags: c++, interpreter

For learning purposes I'm writing an interpreter of arithmetic equations in C++. When the user enters incorrect input, I'd want something like this to appear: (> is user input)

```
> 4+2*6+#-1
Lexer error: incorrect character '#' at position 7
```

What is the best way to approach that? Should I use exceptions, and if yes then should I create my own ones or just use something like `std::runtime_error`?

Comment: Error handling is not done in a vacuum. Priority #1 is being as consistent as possible with the rest of the code it lives alongside with.

Comment: Rule of thumb (guidance) only - if errors are expected then they are not exceptional and probably should not use exceptions. Errors in user input are definitely to be expected.

Comment: I was taught to acknowledge or announce the error as it occurs, then reset to the next safe zone (further lexing or parsing may not be valid).

Comment: @RichardCritten So what would you suggest? Returning something like std::variant with either the expected output or a string with the error message?

Comment: @GOKOP **If** you choose to go with a variant-like type, please have a look at matching the proposed `std::expected<>` instead. There are some [implementations](https://github.com/martinmoene/expected-lite) available as OSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to maintain source location data all the way, through all the compilation passes. This way you can report

- syntax errors, which are the most trivial, you have all the source location data handy at this stage, along with (depending on a parsing technique you're using) hints of what you'd rather expect at this point instead. A lot of such reporting can be inferred automatically with very little hinting.
- semantic errors during compilation: for these you need to keep source locations for your IR nodes. E.g., for a binary arithmetic operation you'll have the location of the operator itself and sub-nodes will be able to show you locations of left and right side. There's no limit to how much information you can carry along here. For example, for any fully resolved identifier you may want to attach a location where it was declared, along with all the locations where it was referenced so far.
- runtime errors: these are tricky, you don't have your rich IR at this stage, but you can emit debugging data in, for example, DWARF format, and unroll it back to your source locations when needed.

Runtime errors should be handled by your system debugger, so, no exceptions here. Semantic errors and syntax errors are, in most cases, recoverable, and you may want to display more than one, so, again, no reason to ever use exceptions.